# Otto unregistering the same instance

Tags: android, otto

I have a BaseFragment which within it's onCreateView method, creates a MyObject class. Both of these are inside a ViewPager.

Two different fragments extends from the `BaseFragment` - `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`.

This means `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` both have their own instances of the MyObject object.

Within the `BaseFragment`, I call `myObject.initialise();` on the `MyObject` object from the `onStart();` method and `cleanUp();` from the `onStop();`

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    myObject.initialise();
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    myObject.cleanUp();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Again - this lives inside the `BaseFragment` so both `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` have this in their lifecycle.

The initialise(); function and cleanUp(); functions look like this:

```
@Override
public void initialise()
{
    BusManager.register(this);
}

@Override
public void cleanUp()
{
    BusManager.unregister(this);
}
```

`FragmentA` will generally close first and it successfully unregisters. When `FragmentB` closes however, it crashes because it think `this` was not registered.

I checked the memory address of `this` and it appears that it tries to `unregister` the same thing twice.

`Missing event handler for an annotated method. Is class com.example.app.MyObject registered?`

Why is it doing this? I have made sure that `MyObject` is a new instance.

Comment: how about using `onCreate()` instead `onStart()` and onDestroy() instead of `onStop()`? Because onStop will be called by the system when we switch from parent activity to another activity. Btw, you maybe need to switch from ottoBus and using [EventBus](https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/) instead. OttoBus is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

For the comment above, note that onDestroy() is not necessary called:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()
You should not count on that for Otto's register / unregister call.

In regarding to Subby's question: I've had scenarios where onStart() / onStop() being called twice. What I ended up is placing a try-catch block. Definitely not a clean solution, but that's how I do before finding out why the lifecycle is messed up.

Comment: It's never called twice. It's always called once. The issue is that the `unregister(this);` method call -> the "this" parameter seems to be an instance of a Fragment which I have previous unregistered.